# cannot useHistory() in React Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am unable to leverage the useHistory() hook to push to a new route.  I declared the useHistory in a Functional Component as follows :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import logo from '../logo.png';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function Login() {

    const [creds,setCreds] = useState({username : "", password : ""});
    let history = useHistory();

    const submitCredentials = event => {
       event.preventDefault();
       axios.get(`${auth.apiURL}/welcome`, { auth: {username : creds.username, password : creds.password}})
         .then(res => console.log(res.data))
         .catch(err => console.error(err));
         history.push('/welcome');
    }

    const handleChange = e => {
        setCreds({...creds,[e.target.name] : e.target.value});
    }


    return (
        <form onSubmit={submitCredentials}>
            <img className="App-logo" src={logo}></img>
            <input name="username" placeholder="username" value={creds.username} onChange={handleChange}></input>
            <input name="password" placeholder="password" value={creds.value} onChange={handleChange}></input>
            <button>Login</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

I get the error :

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Here is my App.js :

```
import './App.css';
import Login from './components/Login.js';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Login/>
      </Route>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm using React Router 17.0.2. with the latest version of React Router 5.2 from npm.

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example on https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/usehistory-login-m39ek?file=/src/App.js.  It is working on the code sandbox link.  Don't know why it's not working on my computer.

Comment: If it is working in sandbox. Try reinstalling packages after deleting node_modules folder and package-lock or yark.lock file. Be careful, don't delete any useful file. Or simply, you can setup a new react project using CRA.

Answer (score 0):

```
import './App.css';
import Login from './components/Login.js';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Router>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Login/>
      </Route>
     </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Try to wrap your Route with Router (Browser Router).